# Azure App Service Application Insights Not showing sql command text in dependency

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights

I have a web app (.Net 4.6.2) running on an Azure App Service with Application Insights. I'm using SQL Azure as a back end. When Application Insights logs sql dependencies, the command text isn't included, just the server name and the database name shows up under 'Command'

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the extension and seem to have exhausted online sources. Can anybody suggest where else I look for a solution?

Comment: Please check the version of the SQL dependency items collected. Is it starting in'rddp' or 'rddf'?
If its not 'rddp', then extension installation hasn't worked.

Comment: It's rddf so I guess it's the wrong version. I just installed it as an extension in my azure web app. How to I fix the installation?

Comment: How are you installing the extension? Are you using the *Application Insights* blade under the *Settings* section of the resource menu on your App Service? If so, does it say the extension is running when you click on *Troubleshooting information* within that blade?

Comment: Initially I used the applications insights blade. I've uninstalled and re-installed via the extensions blade a few times to try to get it working.  The troubleshooting information says that the profile web job is enabled and the webjob monitoring is active. However I have two flags that don't look right: InstrumentationEngineLoaded false and 
 InstrumentationEngineExtensionLoaded false

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this how you install the extension? (Just double checking) And you tried removing/adding back the extension?

Also - does you application refer to SDK in source code already? (via nuget)